# eclipse java oracle database connection

Tags: java, jdbc

Я пытаюсь подключился к базе данных Оракл. Вот мой код:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class BegliConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:testuser/testpass@//Elitecom1:1521/XE");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getInt(1) + "\t");
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

но он выдаёт ошибку:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at BegliConnect.main(BegliConnect.java:18)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BegliConnect.main(BegliConnect.java:31)
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить перед открытием соединения:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Или вот [**так**](http://kbss.ru/blog/oracledb/255.html):

> Открываем `<папку_со_средой>\ide\bin\ide.conf`.
>   Дописываем туда две строчки:
>   `AddVMOption -Duser.language=en`
>   `AddVMOption -Duser.region=us`

Comment: thsnks a lot!!!